# How to insert data in symfony table?

Tags: php, symfony, dql

I have made a symfony form and I used:

```
$conn->insert('Invoiceshasitems', array('Invoiceitemsid' => '$items'));
```

for data insertion but it not works ho i do insert data from symfony controller.
here is my code:

```
$itemscounter = $request->request->get('itemscounter');
if(isset($_SESSION['invoiceid'])) {
    $invoiceid=$_SESSION['invoiceid'];
    //echo $invoiceid;
    //exit;
}
//$entity= new Invoiceshasitems();
if($request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {

    if($itemscounter > 1){

        for($i=1; $i<=$itemscounter; $i++){

            if($i==1){
                $items = $_POST['items'];
            }else {
                $items.$i = $_POST['items'.$i];
            }
        }
    }else{

        $items = $_POST['items'];
        $conn->insert('Invoiceshasitems', array('Invoiceitemsid' => '$items'));
    } 
}
```

Comment: use doctrine: http://symfony.com/it/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Comment: can i used $query = $em->createQuery("insert into Invoiceshasitems('invoiceid','invoiceitemid')values('".$invoiceid."','".$items."')");
      $ids = $query->getResult(); ?

Comment: i used above command but dql only for select,delete,update etc

Comment: another method to insert values other than dql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use native query in Doctrine, there is some docs here: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html

For your example the code is something like that:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
$query = $this->_em->createNativeQuery('INSERT INTO Invoiceshasitems SET Invoiceitemsid = ?', $rsm);
$query->setParameter(1, $items);

$result = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: Link is broken: [http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html)